# Read python variable in maridb query

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mariadb

Im trying to add data into mariadb tables. My prob is how to read variable in mariadb query using python.

Code

```
Values = ['duroc', '0.1', '1']
v0 = Values[0]
v1 = Values[1]
v2 = int(Values[2])
Query = """INSERT INTO t1 (Name, Version, id) VALUES 
                   (v0, v1, v2 ) """
```

Please, who can help me to get the value of v1,v2,v3 in the insert query?
Hope that im clear.

Comment: see: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: @BerndBuffen The [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html) is a lot better than the random garbage that w3schools tends to be. It's the Wikihow of programming.

Comment: @tadman - thanks, i will confirm to your answer

Comment: @Bernd Buffen.. thank you for your suggestion. I was following the examples in the link that you sended.. but didnt solve my problem

Comment: @tadman thnak you for your response.. didnt find an example like am doing.. i dont know what is the problem.. thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Use placeholders in the SQL, then provide the list of values as an argument to `cursor.execute()`

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
Query = """INSERT INTO t1 (Name, Version, id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s) """
cursor.execute(Query, Values)
conn.commit()
```

Comment: thal you for your help. With the place holder i can pass a list directly ?